# How to make my calculation change depending on time period

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm calculating abandonrate for calls in a contact centre. I've managed to get the correct result for the whole data set (9.6%) but when I drill through to month and week, the % becomes wrong.
I would like to have the result show % Total Calls where AbandonedStatus =True and have this % change to be based off of the Time period selected in a separate slicer\filter.

I think I need to take into account date in the TotalCalls measure, but I'm not sure how to do this. I am VERY new with DAX and PowerBI in general.

```
% Abandoned = Calculate(DIVIDE([Abandoned], [Total Calls], 0))

Abandoned = COUNTROWS(FILTER(CallInfo, 
CallInfo'[AbandonedStatus]="True"))

Total Calls = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('CallInfo'), ALL('CallInfo'))
```

At the moment, the result when drilling down to month will always add up to 9.6% (4.09% for Jan, 5.11% for Feb and 0.4% for Mar) where I hope to see the result for that month (11.03% for Jan, 7.88% for Feb and 23.43 for Mar)

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See All function:

ALL(Table) Removes all filters from the specified table.

ALL (Column[, Column[, …]]) Removes all filters from the specified columns in the table; all other filters on other columns in the table still apply.

So if you want to remove only the filter on AbandonedStatus, but not on Date, then use:

Total Calls = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('CallInfo'), ALL('CallInfo'[AbandonedStatus]))